# Enable Hardware Virtualization BIOS - other way?

Tags: windows, laptop, bios, hardware-virtualization

I have a 2009 Asus Pro55 Series Laptop Computer which I use for School and "other work". In this case, I am wanting to try out Mac OS X or Windows 7 via a Virtual Machine or by Dual Booting. I have Dual Booted and created VM's in the past with success.

I currently run Windows 8 Pro, and in the past, I have installed Windows 7 into a VM; whereas Aero is not enabled due to the lack of Hardware Virtualization on my computer.

I have looked in the Computer's BIOS, but there is NO option to enabled Hardware Virtualization.

My computer runs on Core2Duo (T5800) 32bit (compatible to run x64), 2GB RAM, 250GB HHD, ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series (Microsoft Corporation- WDDM v1.1)

I am really wanting to enable Hardware Virtualization to get full performance out of my Virtual Machines and Dual Boot's.

Is there any way to enable it, even though it is not present in my computer's BIOS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You generally don't need VT-x unless you're trying to run a 64 bit guest os on a 32 bit host OS. I don't recall it having anything to do with aero either

Comment: I'm pretty sure things like _any_ 64-bit client and enabling multiple cores on the client require VT-x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, hardware virtualization is a CPU feature that isn't on the T5800 ([source](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology)), so there's no way to enable it with software.

Comment: Mind you, dual booting has nothing to do with virtualization, so you should have full performance there. (you may have knows this already, but it wasn't clear, so I figured I'd clarify)